# How Jenkins manipulate resources when running both Master and Agent within same machine?

Tags: jenkins

Currently my Jenkins has been running in Master-only mode in a Docker container. The master will handler both scheduler and build. However, once running multiple Angular project at the same time the server was down with 100% memory and CPU.

Then I temporary fixed the issue by vertical scaling, added more resources. Which again leaded to the same issue and the resources are useless when there're no project running.

So, I'm considering to do a Jenkins Scalability with master/slave model (since I use cloud and wanted to minimize the costs.)  that also included the limitation of cost for provisioning additional agents by using cloud.

Then, I founded a article 'Running Jenkins Master/Slave in the same machine' that was quite a great solution but I literally don't know how does the Slave will improve the resource issue? If I create containers and assign its as a Salves, they'll use the same host resources.

Please clarify this to me
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said - running more containers on a host will lead to greater resources' usage. The only way is to set resource limits for the containers. Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) article.

Also you need to configure jenkins to use docker from the host, not running containers inside jenkins master's container.

For me it's better to use horizontal scaling with small instances and pay for hosts/container while they are running, instead of vertical scaling.

Also you can read [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/) article regarding hardware recommendations to run jenkins.